# Cannot run rails server with mysql2 on windows server 2003

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-2.0, mysql2

**Server**: IBM xseries 3550

**OS**: Windows Server 2003

**Ruby**: 2.0.0

**Rails**: 3.2

**MySQL**: 5.5

I installed mysql2 gem with `with gem install mysql2 --no-ri --no-rdoc -- --with-mysql-dir=C:\mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32` and it successfully installed and the ***mysql.so*** file has been created.
Afterwards, I copied the ***libmysql.dll*** to the ruby200 bin directory.

Error: `C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.rb:8in 'require': 127: The specified procedure could not be found. - C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.so <LoadError>`

btw, I installed ruby2 with mysql2 on other *windows 7* pc and it worked just fine.

Thanks for your helps!
Shalev

Comment: You sure C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.so exists?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, 59Kb file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the **mysql** and not the **mysql connector**:

`gem install mysql2 --
     '--with-mysql-lib="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\lib"
      --with-mysql-include="c:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\include"'`

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you! I copied the dll file from the mysql and it worked!